# cordova app shows only background color on iOS 9

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

When building our Cordova app to and iPad 2 it only shows the background colour. All other builds work as should: iPhones (10.3.3), Androids, all work.

I can't find an error in the console. No clue how even to start to debug this.

iPad iOs version: 9.3.5

Plugins:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.6" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
<plugin name="uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.istablet" spec="^1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.2.3" />
```

Comment: What version of iOS is your iPad 2 running and what versions have you tested on other iDevices?

Comment: Updated the iVersions tested.

Comment: So the problem is with iOS 9? And you're only seeing the page background color, no content? What does the Elements panel is Safari Web Inspector show? And are there any errors in its Console?

Comment: Yes, the problem is with iOs 9. We have an iPhone 4s with the same issue.

Comment: Oh, now we have an error: `Failed to load resource` Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think it's an access allowance thing. But trying `<base href="/">` don't work. As does `allow-intent`

Comment: Opened the .ipa file, all is there...